# criteria for a short exact sequence of finite groups to be split

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose you have a short exact sequence of finite groups

$1\rightarrow N\rightarrow F\rightarrow G\rightarrow 1$
such that $|G|$ and $|N|$ are coprime. Must the sequence be split? (Here I mean the existence of a section $G\rightarrow F$)

Comment: Interesting fact: You do not even need the coprime assumption if the group is solvable.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth Yes you do!

Comment: ohh sorry yes we do, we can drop solvable condition(to say complements are conjugates) by invoking feit-thompson but co-prime is must Oops my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the [Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_theorem).